# How to include bokeh chart into robot framework html report

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, bokeh

I try to include a bokeh chart into Robot Framework HTMl report.

I use logger.info() from from robot.api import logger to inject the code into the report.
I can include a simple html tag like , but the trick does not work with bokeh.

```
from robot.api import logger
from bokeh.plotting import figure

class customreport(object):
    def my_test_keyword(self, message):
        p = figure()
        p.circle([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
        script, div = bokeh.embed.components(p)
        logger.info(script, html=True)
        logger.info(div, html=True)
```

The script is in the code, but won't load.

Comment: I took a look and issue could be that bokeh's actual library is not loaded when you view the report. You could verify this by opening your generated report and go to dev console, wait a while and see if it has following in the console: Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing

Comment: And to fix that, you probably need to print also `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` or something similar ? However, that would mean that resulting report is not viewable when offline as that would fetch the js file from CDN -- you could also try to embed that file directly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to being curious, i made a small proof of concept to just check if and how this is possible.

Here's a small robot suite:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    bkdemo

*** Test Cases ***
Bokeh Demo
  Generate Figure
```

And keyword library bkdemo.py

```py
from robot.api import logger
import bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import figure

def generate_figure():
    p = figure()
    p.circle([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
    script, div = bokeh.embed.components(p)

    # Get Rid of the script tags
    script = script.replace('<script type="text/javascript">','')
    script = script.replace('</script>','')

    # Where to load the bokeh
    url = "https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-3.3.1.min.js"
    # use jquery getScript to get a callback once bokeh is loaded and then
    # run the script from bokeh.embed.components
    force_load_bokeh = f"$.getScript('{url}', function(){{{script}}});"
    logger.info(f'<script type="text/javascript">{force_load_bokeh}</script>', html=True)

    # and then print the location where bokeh does rendering
    logger.info(div, html=True)
```

Now, *if* robot framework would have possibility to customize its html templates, and as mentioned in comments, most of the "hacks" (eg, use of jquery and stripping returned script) would be unnecessary when one could just add the script tag to load or embed bokeh into top level html ..

But atleast i can see the chart being rendered now ;)

Comment: https://github.com/rasjani/rf-bokeh-demo <- standalone project